# Refactoring Realm to use threading

Tags: android, multithreading, realm, rx-java

Decided to give a Realm w/threading a shot.

I have a Repository class with method in which I push some `Data` to the Realm. Another method is slightly transforming `Data` as needed. There is one query method as well, which does `findAllSorted()` on `Data` class and returns `Observable` with results.

---

I started first with wrapping all method code (including getting Realm instance) in `Observables` and doing `.subscribeOn(Schedulers.single())`.

Insertions worked fine, but doing `realm.where(Image::class.java).findAll(...)` is throwing *"need to be executed on thread with a looper"*. Adding `observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread)` throws *"objects can only be accessed on the thread they were created"*. The same story goes when I refactored all Observables to run on UI thread with `subscribeOn`.

---

So I thought, I'll go step back to using Realm integrated threading model instead (methods with suffix `Async`). Right now insertions don't work since Realm is spawning multiple unique threads for each `realm.executeTransactionAsync`, so "insert" operation is run on Pool-1-Thread-1 thread, while "transform" operation is run on Pool-1-Thread-2 so, obviously, *"objects can only be accessed on the thread they were created"*.

Anybody here used Realm with threading? To be honest, I feel like I fell for some practical joke. Thanks!

Comment: I mean, Realm at its basics assumes that you will solve threading by letting Realm handle threading (using the async methods), and otherwise not try to pass managed Realm stuff between threads.

Comment: Yes, that's true, that's why I rolled back to using Realm's tools for handling threading. Now every time I execute transaction (realm.executeTransactionAsync) it is done on different thread, so I get "Realm objects can only be accessed on the thread they were created.". That's why I am willing to draw the conclusion that if Realm can't handle it's own threading and I cannot help him with rx - it is just impossible to do so. Lack of comprehensive resources on that topic doesn't work in it's advantage as well.

Comment: `Lack of comprehensive resources on that topic` ....i'm actually kinda *scheduled* for writing an article about it (stay tuned) but the trick is that Realm expects to be exposed as an Observable while obeying its requirement for thread confinement, meaning you can wrap the RealmChangeListener as an Observable. The observable can therefore emit only after `findAllSortedAsync()` has finished loading the results, and on future changes. For writes, I recommend a dedicated single-threaded executor (Rx makes that easy), considering `beginTransaction()` is blocking across threads anyways.

Comment: Well, your articles on Medium are spot on, I'd love to read one about threading in Realm. I guess I'll just drop asynchronousness for now and wait until your article rolls out. Looking forward to it!